# send custom parameters to user control ascx

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I need to use user controls (.ascx) on a page, it's a related post user control based in 2 parameters:

```
 1. Current post
 2. Relation type
```

the page needs to have 3 different instances of this control, each having the same Current post parameter, but different relation type (title, author, genre).

The 1st parameter I can get it through url, but what about the second parameter?

I've been googling for a while but i haven't found an answer yet. How can I pass the second parameter so the control can load the information based on these parameters? 
I'd rather not to create a control for each parameter, else would be better to build no user control but direct into code :(
Thanks!

Comment: Why dont just create properties (of the ascx) and just assign that from the page which is using it?

Comment: You mean
`<my:Control runat="server" MyPublicProperty="Value1" MyPublicProperty2="Value2"/>`
How can I read those properties from the control?

Comment: as these properties are control(class) properties, it can always read/write those

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Create public properties of the user-control like:

```
public partial class SampleUC : UserControl
{
    public string CurrentPost {get;set;}
    public string RelationType {get;set;}

    //...

    //...
}
```

Assign those from the page using it either from markup like:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" TagName="SampleUC" Src="SampleUC.ascx" %>
...
...
<cc:SampleUC id="myUC" runat="server" CurrentPost="Sample Post Title" RelationType="Title" />
```

or from code-behind (of the page using it):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...

    myUC.CurrentPost = "Sample Post Title";
    myUC.RelationType = "Title" ;

    //...
}
```

Comment: If it's not painfully clear to anyone else, make sure to put the setting of the properties outside of the `!IsPostBack` block in the code-behind of the page on which you are using the control. They end up blank on postback otherwise.

Comment: What if I want to send `objects` instead of strings ?

Comment: @amd Then you can't use the asp markup (in the aspx page); but you can set it in code-behind (c#).