# ASP web forms constructor parameters by markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a web forms server control:

```
public class MyControl: <...>
{
 public MyControl(int param){<...>}
}
```

And I need to use this control as this:

```
<my:MyControl runnat=server param=15 ... />
```

How can I develop this behavior?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16205725/1520969) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Write a property into your UserControl

```
    public int param {get; set;}
```

Comment: it is not a constructor